# how to input the length by clicking on the chart

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

How not to have to click on the status line of the indicator and open it to input the number of periods or length?

I believe there is a way to set the length of the indicator by clicking directly on a chart bar, without having to open the widgets pane of the indicator.

For example, if I wanted to input a length which is 37, I would only have to click on the bar which is 37 bars back from the last.

Alternatively, is there a point and drag solution?

I have read about the confirm argument but it's definitely not what I'm looking for...

```
movePeriods = input.int(defval=37, title='movePeriods', minval=3, maxval=1439, tooltip='move duration')
```